# Android simpledateformat not working properly

Tags: android, timezone

So my code to convert the current time to UTC time format is given below:

```
Date currentDate = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd kk:mm:ss");
sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
String UTCTime= sdf.format(currentDate);
```

But it doesn't work for some reason, it is still giving the current time in my timezone instead of the UTC timezone. Does anyone know what is causing the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the code is working, my phone had the wrong timezone setting